# Uncaught Error: Not enough space for Photobooth. Min height / width is 200 px

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Im a using a Webcam Plugin http://wolframhempel.github.io/photobooth-js/

After using , its giving me the following error:

```
Error: Not enough space for Photobooth. Min height / width is 200 px
```

Below is the javascript code:

```
container = document.getElementById( "example" );
gallery = document.getElementById( "gallery" );
myPhotobooth = new Photobooth( container );
myPhotobooth.onImage = function( dataUrl ){ 
    var myImage = document.createElement( "img" );
    myImage.src = dataUrl; 
    gallery.appendChild( myImage );
};
```

HTML code:

```
<div id = "example"></div>
<div id = "gallery"></div>
```

Is it a bug or something?

Comment: yes , but still nothing works...

Comment: added a working example, see again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the message is clear: you need a container with min height and width. So, set `min-height` and `min-width` to `example`, that's your container.

Something like this:

```
<div id="example" style="min-height: 200px; min-width: 200px;"></div>
```

Or this, in a CSS file or `<style>`:

```
#example {
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

Other way is set fixed width and height, like this:

```
<div id="example" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Or this, in a CSS file or `<style>`:

```
#example {
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

**EDIT:** see an working example:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var container = document.getElementById("example");
  var gallery = document.getElementById("gallery");
  var myPhotobooth = new Photobooth(container);
  myPhotobooth.onImage = function(dataUrl) {
    var myImage = document.createElement("img");
    myImage.src = dataUrl;
    gallery.appendChild(myImage);
  };
});
```

```css
#example {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://wolframhempel.github.io/photobooth-js/photobooth_min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
<div id="gallery"></div>
```